# Why I got incorrect calculation of COUNT DISTINCT with GROUP BY?

Tags: sql, group-by, count, distinct

I have a table INTERACTIONS

```
CustomerID | Channel | Response
-----------+---------+----------
 245       | SMS     | Accept   
 245       | PUSH    | Ignore   
 247       | SMS     | Accept   
 249       | PUSH    | Ignore
```

When I make request

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT CUSTOMERID) AS Customers 
FROM INTERACTIONS;
```

I get result `7440`

When I make query with group by Channel, and then calculate sum for all groups:

```
    SELECT SUM(CUSTOMERS) 
    FROM 
        (SELECT 
             CHANNEL,
             COUNT(DISTINCT CUSTOMERID) AS Customers 
         FROM 
             INTERACTIONS
         GROUP BY 
             CHANNEL);
```

I get result `9993`

Why? What's wrong? I expect that number of all customers is the same.

Comment: Some customers are in multiple channels.

Answer (score 2):

It is right there in your sample data. The distinct customers are:

```
245, 247, 249
```

When you group by channel the `245` customer appears separately for PUSH and SMS:

```
SMS  | 245, 247
PUSH | 245, 249
```

Thus `COUNT(DISTINCT x) GROUP BY y` could be greater than `COUNT(DISTINCT x) -- NO GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 1):

you got different result because  different  CHANNEL `PUSH` and `SMS` contains same id 245 , as a result when you  `COUNT(DISTINCT CUSTOMERID)` in 1st query it will return 1 but when 
you applied group by CHANNEL it will return per group 1 so your 2nd query 245 id will make `push=1 and sms=1` and final query sum() will make it 2 which is different result

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT CHANNEL,
COUNT(DISTINCT CUSTOMERID) AS Customers 
FROM INTERACTIONS
GROUP BY CHANNEL
```

That query gives you distinct `CUSTOMERID` **per Channel**. It is possible that same `CUSTOMERID` values exist among different Channels, thus they would be counted that many times in the final sum (9993).

You could check that out by converting the query to this one, that would give you the number of Channels per CUSTOMERID:

```
SELECT CUSTOMERID,
COUNT(DISTINCT CHANNEL) AS Channels
FROM INTERACTIONS
GROUP BY CHANNEL
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT CHANNEL) > 1
```