# Is it possible to use grouped-by "count distinct" results in the same query?

Tags: sql, db2

I asked a question before [Why I got the incorrect calculation of COUNT DISTINCT with GROUP BY?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53556396/why-i-got-incorrect-calculation-of-count-distinct-with-group-by) now I understand why.

But the fact that the same customer could be duplicated in different channels - it is a problem.

My main goal in this question is to calculate the percentage of interacted customers by channel.

Table INTERACTIONS

```
CustomerID | Channel | Response
-----------+---------+----------
 245       | SMS     | Accept   
 245       | PUSH    | Ignore   
 247       | SMS     | Accept   
 249       | PUSH    | Ignore
```

The formula is simple:

```
Percentage_by_channel = Customers_number_by_channel * 100 / All_customers
```

- `Customers_number_by_channel` - is count distinct select.
- `All_customers` - is a sum of customers by all channels.

So I want to know is possible to make such SQL query?

I couldn't get All_customers before I get customers number by channels. But I need to calculate percentage while getting results by channel. And it is a problem.

Can you give me the right way to make SQL query "calculating the percentage of interacted customers by channel"?

UPDATE: desired result:

```
 Channel | Customers_number | Customers_percentage
---------+------------------+----------------------
 SMS     |   1000           |       10             
 PUSH    |   3000           |       30             
 CALL    |   6000           |       60
```

Comment: Provide desired results of this sample data.

Comment: What is the expected output for the given data. I count 50% SMS 50% PUSH unless I am missing something.

Comment: Added desired results table

Comment: Database is DB2. Added tag to my question.

Comment: @AlekseyKurkov . . . You realize that the numbers will typically add up to more than 100%.

Comment: @GordonLinoff yes, I realize. Thats why I want to find the way to get dynamically customers count by channel, and then calculate the sum for all channels for total customers number value.

Comment: IRL I report counts not percentages.  Its very easy to convert a count to a percentage on a user report.  but a percentage can't be converted back to a count.  This way when boss [wo]man asks for the total count you'll have something that can be reused.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the numbers to add up to 100%, as in your example, then use window functions:

```
SELECT channel, 
       (count(distinct customerid) * 1.0 /
        sum(count(distinct customerid)) over ()
       ) as ratio
FROM interactions
GROUP BY channel;
```

Note that customers can have interactions in more than one channel, so this is really the ratio of customer-channel pairs.

Otherwise, a_horse_with_no_name has the solution over all customers, but the numbers will not add to 100%.

Comment: I tried your SQL querry, and it retuned table with 0 ratio values for every channel

Comment: @AlekseyKurkov . . . That is no doubt an integer division error, easily fixed by multiplying by 1.0.